# Can´t add action to Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions

Tags: global-actions, publisher-action

I'm new as salesforce developer and maybe this question is very easy but I can't find any way to solve.

I want to create a new action for my mobile users for adding some information easily.

- I've created a new global action with a predefined value and now i'm trying to add it to the publisher layout for mobile.

At this point, I'm stuck because i can't drop the action as you can see...
Any idea?
[image]

Comment: Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section can contain actions only from the Mobile & Lightning Actions category in the palette. On object page layouts, the Mobile & Lightning Actions category contains all available types of actions for the object, including quick actions, productivity actions, Lightning component actions, and standard and custom buttons. Actions in this section appear in the action bar and action menu in the Salesforce mobile app and in various areas of Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure in the top left panel, you have selected the Mobile & Lightning Action item. Otherwise it will not allow you to add. Please refer below - 
[image]

[image]